# Sampling method for constructing multiple groups from a given pool

Tags: r, sampling

There is a set A having $N$ elements. Based on set A,  I would like to construct $M$ groups, where each group has $P$ elements. Naturally, $M P <N$.   All of those elements in the $M$ groups are sampled from set A by following the two criteria, they are different with each other; the sampling probability for each of these MP elements are the same.

Which kind of sampling method should I use? How to do that in R?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "based on set A"? And you write that "Naturally, M *P", what do you mean by that? Did you mean that $M\times P=N$?

Comment: "based on set A" means that all of those M*P elements are sampled from A. M*P can be smaller than N.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A <- LETTERS[1:20]
M <- 4
P <- 3
matrix(sample(A,size=M*P),nrow=M, ncol=P)
```

Then each row of the matrix gives you one group of size $P$. Alternatively, you can sample with replacement:

```
matrix(sample(A,size=M*P,replace=TRUE),nrow=M, ncol=P)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I understand the usage of "sample" this way, if I do not include the parameter of "prob" when using sample. All of the sampled ones are given the same probability, 1/MP. Otherwise, I can use parameter "prob" to control the selection probability for each sampled one.

Comment: Exactly correct!